# Semantic UI Card with image on the left

Tags: css, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-css

Is it possible using Semantic UI Card have the image on the left? The documentation shows example where the image is always on the top. What i want to obtain is something like the Semantic UI Item (but of course i want use cards), like this:

[image]

What i want to obtain is something like this:

[image]

As you can see the image is on the left and it is something similar to a Semantic UI card.

Comment: I think it is impossible with only Semantic UI css classes but I will be glad to see possible solution and use it for myself, that is why +1

Answer (score 4):

The best you can do with semantic components would be this:

```
<div class="ui card" style="max-width: 100%; min-width: 100%;">
    <div class="content" style="padding: 0;">
        <div class="ui items">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="ui medium image">
                    <img src="https://semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/image.png">
                </div>
                <div class="content" style="padding: 1rem;">
                    <a class="header">12 Years a Slave</a>
                    <div class="meta">
                        <span class="cinema">Union Square 14</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extra">
                        <div class="ui label">IMAX</div>
                        <div class="ui label"><i class="globe icon"></i> Additional Languages</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="extra content">
        <a>
            More Info
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have changed the `padding` on the content but that's the only custom CSS used.

To get it to look exactly like your image you will need to make your own component/style it your self.